# Android Constraint Layout Center Aligning Horizontally With Textview and Imageview Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image: I want like this]

i want my textview and imageview like above mentioned image.

1.I want to set the **Textview and Imageview Horizontally** in single line using constraint layout.

2.Textview is not coming to middle(center) of the Imageview.(left and right position)

3.Also layout gravity is not working to make **textview center**,due to Cosntraint layout

4.Help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv1">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Hero"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/display_pic"
                    />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/display_pic"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title1"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: i want to set the textview and imageview in center horizontal position using constraint layout, not vertically.

Comment: You want to overlap the ImageView and the TextView? It is not clear

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler left side of the parent i want textview , right side of the textview i want imageview .

Comment: Ok, check the answer that I posted, It would work

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler check my updated question.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the `ImageView` in the right side of the parent remove this attribute:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title1"
```

And if you want to align vertically the `TextView` add these attributes:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/display_pic"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/display_pic"
```

The xml with changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Hero"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/display_pic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/display_pic"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/display_pic"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: You want the TextView inside the ImageView?

Comment: no left side -textview right side-imageview in the same line horizontally so that textview should be center to imageview

Comment: Post an image please

Comment: Just remove this line then             `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/title1"`

Comment: app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" like this it s der in my code

Comment: Remove the `constraintLeft` in the ImageView

Comment: nothing changed:(

Comment: See the edit, that's the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163770/discussion-between-kumar-and-juan-cruz-soler).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hero"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With above code you can keep textview in the center of image view. To position the image view, adjust vertical and horizonrtal bias. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, see my updated Question with image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the one you want! see the image and comment

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: imageview size is not  increasing its fixed .this is not expected answer.

Comment: @kumar I just checked the code with increased size of the image and setting up scale type of image of my snippet its perfectly aligned here! no matter what image size is

Comment: Hai check my updated Question.